# How can I set permissions so that a user cannot delete their home directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

For example: I have `kuan/lap1`.

I want the user to be able to read, write, and delete inside the folder `kuan` but not to be able to delete folder `kuan`. Only root should be able to delete the folder.

Comment: By default, users should already not be able to delete their own home directories (because `/home` itself is only writable by `root`)

Answer (score 2):

Like what @steeldriver said, users should not be able to delete their home directory, as `/home` is owned by `root`. I have tested this on my Ubuntu machine to confirm the logic holds up :D

EDIT:
Ok, so here's an example:

```
# As root
mkdir outerDir # The wrapper dir
mkdir outerDir/innerDir # The directory you want the user to have access to, but not delete
chown youruser:youruser outerDir/innerDir # Change ownership to your user
```

Since `/home` is already owned by root, `youruser` should be able to create & edit files & such within `/home/youruser`, but not delete `/home/youruser` itself

You also need to watch for permissions. Your outer directory, or `/home`, should be readable by all users, but only writable by `root`, and the inner directory, or `/home/youruser`, should be readable & writable by your user, but not by any others. An example of this with `chmod`:

```
# As root
chmod 755 outerDir # Make the outer directory readable by all
chmod 700 outerDir/innerDir # Make the inner directory only accesible to the user who owns it
```

The numbers I gave are in the order of user, group, and other. `7` means it's readable, writable, and executable. `5` means it's readable and writable, and `0` means no access, so `755` means it's readable, writable, and executable by the user who owns the file, and readable and executable by the group that owns it & everyone else; `700` means it's readable, writable, and executable by the user that owns it, and by nobody else. If you want to read more about `chmod`, try [this](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm), it's just the first result Googling "chmod"

Comment: I see that there are downvotes, but why? I'm not angry, just want feedback

Comment: The down-vote is not from me, but I think the reason for it could be that you don't write a single word about permissions, only about ownership. But permissions are an important thing too. Reread @steeldrivers comment. He wrote that `/home` is writable by only `root`, not that `/home` is owned by `root` (even if that is the case). Ownership and permission go together!

Comment: @mook765 thank you! I've edited my answer now

Answer (score -2):

If you want users to each have a private /home directory, but not be able to access other's /home directory do 'chmod 700 $HOME' but this must be performed by each user's home directory. Another way is doing it with the sudo account, or you may enable root by doing 'sudo passwd root' after prompt setting passwd for root, to switch to the root account 'su' enter root passwd, then you may from root chmod each user's home directory according to each's privileges and needs. Also, 'chmod 700 directoryname' works.